# START_EXCLUDE in Android Java code

Tags: java, android, firebase

Sometimes I see statements like

```
// [START on_create]
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    // Invite button click listener
    findViewById(R.id.invite_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
```

That is Google's official example code for Firebase invites: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/3dba5755c37b74dccadec5149231e783e84e9bec/invites/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/invites/MainActivity.java#L54

It looks like Google staff uses some meta-tool for code handling, but I do not know it. Just interesting, what is it?